# Shifting Frequency of a VHF Crystal?

Tags: vhf

I have a boatload of 165.550 MHz Regency 10.7 MHz IF Crystals.  I need them to resonate for 165.500 MHz.  How can I shift the crystal frequency down 50 KHz without opening the 'tincan' and messing with it?  Can I add a small capacitor in parallel to shift the crystal frequency down? How can I determine the value of the Cap? Likewise, is there a rule of thumb in order raise the frequency of a crystal?  Is 50KC too big of a jump?
Thanks Much, 73
J

Answer (score 3):

You can add inductance in a sequence like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0BoBm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes, you can also try adding capacitance in parallel.